# python urllib returns two 0xfffd characters instead of expected unicode characters

Tags: python, unicode

I'm scraping some website, encoding is unicode:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

To do that I use urllib:

```
html = unicode(urllib.openurl(url).read(), 'utf-8')
```

Sometimes some of the unicode characters will be replaced with two 0xFFFD characters at random. I guess that a single character encoded with 4 bytes gets broken, and is replaced with two 0xFFFD for each of the two 2-byte halves. The probability of such replacement is pretty low - maybe one character in 500 000 is replaced, something about that. It seems like only non-ascii characters are being corrupted.

I don't observe any of these replacements when the same page is rendered in browser.

How do I identify which part introduces the problem? Is it the server that sends corrupted bytes or the client that doesn't read them properly?

@John Machin:

1. Python version is 2.7.1
2. It's observable in all browsers as well as in most of http client (libcurl, wget, python)
3. I actually was wrong here - sometimes these errors show up in browsers on the rendered page. The errors appear like two diamond characters with question marks.
4. The errors are random. Sometimes they show up, sometimes no. The larger the page is, the larger the chance is that the error will show up.

So I think that the error is introduced on the web server side. I will just try to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do a lot of magic to correct invalid characters. Try looking at the raw bytes returned by `.read()` and check to see if the source page has invalid characters. For example, sometimes pages will encode accented letters with latin-1 or similar, and other characters with utf-8.

Comment: The characters break down randomly. So there might be a sequence of repeating strings and one character in one of the string will be broken. But I will check the raw bytes to see what the values of broken bytes are, this will probably answer my question at least partly...

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities.

1. If the `.read()` call returns only part of a multi-byte sequence at the end, then the partial sequence would be replaced by U+FFFD.  See [this explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Design) of UTF-8 encoding.  Partial byte sequences can be detected easily using the number of leading 1 bits in the first byte of an encoded codepoint, so that you can decode everything except the partial sequence and resume with the next read.  Codepoints U+007F and lower are encoded with one byte, so this problem could never affect those codepoints.
2. Perhaps the document contains the `charset=utf-8` declaration, but is not actually encoded with UTF-8.  Any bytes then that don't happen to be a valid UTF-8 sequence would then be replaced by U+FFFD.

If you post some example byte sequences obtained from the server, for each individual read operation, and the character-strings that result from those bytes, we can be more certain what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible that the server and client are reproducing faithfully the results of an earlier stuffup. Scenario: Somebody has text encoded in `cp1252` (the usual suspect). They decode it using UTF-8 with the "replace" option -- introducing u"\ufffd" -- and then encode the result.

Example original text: `Seine Füße sind wund.`

```
>>> original = "Seine F\xfc\xdfe sind wund." # encoded in cp1252
>>> ucode1 = original.decode('utf8', 'replace')
>>> ucode1
u'Seine F\ufffd\ufffde sind wund.'
>>> input_to_server = ucode1.encode('utf8')
>>> input_to_server
'Seine F\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbde sind wund.'
>>> observed_result = unicode(input_to_server, 'utf8')
>>> observed_result
u'Seine F\ufffd\ufffde sind wund.'
>>>
```

In any case, all answers will be based on guesswork if you don't supply more information, like:

- What version of Python (precisely please, e.g. 2.7.1)
- What browser(s) are you inspecting the url with? What does the "view 
  text" tell you?
- You say "I don't observe any of these replacements when the same page
  is rendered in browser." OK, so you are getting `rhubarb \ufffd\ufffd
  artichoke` from your code and in the browser you see `rhubarb
  PLEASE-TELL-US-WHAT-YOU-SEE-HERE artichoke` -- please divulge.
- Any good reason why you can't divulge the url that you are having the
  problem with?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back on it before. This issue is still present and important. Since the job is to scrape some data from a website, I can afford to ignore these errors or make an additional call, that wont yield those errors in the same spot. I added answers to your questions to the question.